# Result of FFTW 1D stored in transposed way

Tags: c, fftw

I am wondering if it is possible to store the transposed matrix of a 1D FFT call from FFTW.
Consider my matrix `nrows_1 x w_size`.At the moment it is stored in chunks of size `w_size`

```
for (ix = 0 ; ix < nrows_1 ; ix++)
    {
      plan =  fftw_plan_dft_1d(w_size, &source_data[ix*w_size], &transposed_data[ix*w_size],
                   FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
      fftw_execute(plan);
    }
```

So I would like to transpose the result matrix using the FFTW call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Advanced Complex DFT](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html) of FFTW. All the dft may be performed at once thanks to parameter `howmany` and the output is transposed, if parameters `ostride` and `odist` are properly set.

The following code demonstrates how it works. It is compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3 -lm` :

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int n=9;
    int m=4;

    fftw_complex *datasource=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*m*n);
    fftw_complex *dataoutput=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*m*n);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            datasource[i*m+j][0]=(i+j)%4+j*j+i*i*i;
            datasource[i*m+j][1]=0;
        }
    }

    printf("input :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%g ",datasource[i*m+j][0]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    fftw_plan plan;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        plan =  fftw_plan_dft_1d(m, &datasource[i*m], &dataoutput[i*m],
                FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute(plan);
        fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    }

    printf("expected output, real part, not transposed :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%g ",dataoutput[i*m+j][0]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    plan=fftw_plan_many_dft(1, &m, n,
            datasource, NULL, 1, m,
            dataoutput, NULL,n, 1,
            FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

    printf("output, real part, already transposed :\n");
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%g ",dataoutput[j*n+i][0]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fftw_free(datasource);
    fftw_free(dataoutput);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess my answer comes too late to be useful...